# Map collection attributes in JPA entity from SQL view

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, sql-view

I have the following Entities, `User` and `Policy`. A User can have multiple policies. I wanted to avoid associations between them, firstly, because the logic behind which policies belong to which user would depend on other things as well, and secondly, to avoid linking aggregate roots by direct reference, so I only store an identifier in the Entity classes.

In order to get a user together with all his attached policies, I decided to create a SQL view, for future reference let's call it `user_permission_view`, which would look something like this, simplified for brevity

```
 CREATE VIEW "user_permission_view" AS
 SELECT * FROM "users"
 LEFT OUTER JOIN "permissions"
 ON "users"."id" = "permissions"."userId"
```

The resulting view would have the attributes of both `User` and `Policy`. I decided to map this to a Java class called `UserPolicyView`. However, I'm struggling with how to map the attributes from `Policy` into a collection field inside the `UserPolicyView`.

Is it possible to do something like this with JPA? Do I need to define associations to the `Policy` entity from inside `UserPolicyView`? How would that affect the generated SQL, if the view already contains a `JOIN` clause?

Edit:

One possible solution I came up with was to discard the `user_permission_view` entirely, declare an embeddable `PolicyDetails` object, create a view containing all user permissions, and use `@ElementCollection` to specify that view as the source table. Would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> declare an embeddable PolicyDetails object, create a view containing all user permissions, and use @ElementCollection to specify that view as the source table. Would that work?

From a technical point of view - yes, it should work (I'll refrain from commenting on whether it's a sound idea from the point of view of domain modelling). You might also want `@Immutable`, to prevent accidental modification attempts.

As regards your earlier suggestion - you'll only be able to map it as the flattened structure that the view represents. No collection fields, I'm afraid. You can, of course, choose to map only some of the view columns onto properties. But, I suppose that's not what you're after.

Comment: Yes, I came to the same conclusion. I decided to declare SQL views for every aggregate, map these views to `@Immutable` entities, and declare the associations in there.